# Retrieve variable names from metagraph

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently trying to retrieve trained TF models from another project (https://github.com/pathak22/noreward-rl, on the vizdoom platform).

I have successfully managed to import the models in my new project using:

```
session = tf.Session()
print("Loading model from: ", model_savefile)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_savefile + '.meta')
saver.restore(session, model_savefile)
```

However, I do not have access to the code that generated this savefile (I think it was through OpenAI Gym, but no certainty), and therefore I do not know the names I should use to feed it my inputs.

Do you know how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Importing a `MetaGraph` will add operations to the default graph.

Print all operations in a graph:

```
print(tf.get_default_graph().get_operations())
```

Prints something like:

```
[<tf.Operation 'Placeholder' type=Placeholder>, <tf.Operation 'mul/y' type=Const>, <tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>]
```

Print just the placeholders:

```
print([op for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.type == 'Placeholder'])
```

Prints something like:

```
[<tf.Operation 'Placeholder' type=Placeholder>]
```